# Android Http request casting error

Tags: android, authentication, autologin

I am stuck at this Http Request file that keeps giving me a casting error. I am new to login over the network, so I followed a tutorial that had deprecated code for HttpParams imports, I found a solution here asking me to import and include dependencies from `cz.msebera.android.httpclient` as in the code snippets bellow but I am now getting a casting error that I do not understand. Any help with this would be appreciated. My android app is for a user login and registration

```
package com.geeky.systems.personal.als;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.HttpEntity;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.HttpResponse;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.NameValuePair;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.HttpClient;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.methods.HttpPost;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.params.BasicHttpParams;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.params.HttpParams;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.util.EntityUtils;

//import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
//import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

public class ServerRequests {
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
public final static int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 1000 * 20;
public final static String SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://upishi.net/";

public ServerRequests(Context context){
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Processing");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
}

public void storeUserDataInBackground(User user, GetUserCallback userCallback){
    progressDialog.show();
    new storeUserDataAsyncTask(user, userCallback).execute();
}

public void fetchUserDataInBackground(User user, GetUserCallback callBack){
    progressDialog.show();
    new fetchUserDataAsyncTask(user, callBack).execute();
}

public class storeUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    User user;
    GetUserCallback userCallback;

    public storeUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallback userCallback){

        this.user = user;
        this.userCallback = userCallback;

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", user.name));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("occupation", user.occupation));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender", user.gender));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", user.email));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", user.age + ""));

        HttpParams httpRequestParams = (HttpParams) new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient((ClientConnectionManager) httpRequestParams);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "Register.php");

        try{
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            client.execute(post);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        userCallback.done(null);
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}

public class fetchUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, User> {
    User user;
    GetUserCallback userCallback;

    public fetchUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallback userCallback) {

        this.user = user;
        this.userCallback = userCallback;

    }

    @Override
    protected User doInBackground(Void... params) {

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));

        HttpParams httpRequestParams = (HttpParams) new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient((ClientConnectionManager) httpRequestParams);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "FetchUserData.php");

        User returnedUser = null;
        try{
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);

            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);

            if (jObject.length()==0){
                returnedUser = null;
            }else{
                String name = jObject.getString("name");
                String occupation = jObject.getString("occupation");
                String gender = jObject.getString("gender");
                String email = jObject.getString("email");
                int age = jObject.getInt("age");

                returnedUser = new User(name,user.username,user.password,occupation,gender,email,age);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return returnedUser;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(User returnedUser) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        userCallback.done(returnedUser);
        super.onPostExecute(returnedUser);
    }
}

}
```

The error I am getting looks like this

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cz.msebera.android.httpclient.params.BasicHttpParams cannot be cast to cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ClientConnectionManager
  at com.geeky.systems.personal.als.ServerRequests$storeUserDataAsyncTask.doInBackground(ServerRequests.java:80)
  at com.geeky.systems.personal.als.ServerRequests$storeUserDataAsyncTask.doInBackground(ServerRequests.java:54)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 
  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) 
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: When asking questions, please format your code/logs for maximum readability (thanks @martijnn2008) and please refrain from begging for urgency - it isn't urgent to **volunteers** here.

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpParams httpRequestParams = (HttpParams) new BasicHttpParams();
(...)
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient((ClientConnectionManager) httpRequestParams);
```

Unless BasicHttpParams is a subclass of ClientConnectionManager (which is probably not the case), then you are sure to get a ClassCastException here ! Casting "parameters" to a "connection manager" does not make much sense to me :-)